# Save all images using names of materials

Tags: import

I have an imported model I'm working with. The materials by default are named something like 054fF0_c. I usually rename all of these in blender to something that makes more sense. I would like to then 'Save all images' of the opened images in the UV editor window but I want them to have the names that I assigned in the material tab and not suggest the original name that's not my assignment. Is there a way to already accomplish this? I'm not a programmer by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The following script should resave your images the way you want. Copy and paste this into [blenders text editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/text_editor.html) and click Run Script.

If the same image is used by multiple materials, it will save a copy of the image for each material but only one will be used for all materials.

```
import bpy
import os

editor = bpy.context.screen.areas[1]
old_type = editor.type
editor.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
override = bpy.context.copy()
override['area'] = editor

def rename_image(img, mat_name, img_count):
    editor.spaces.active.image = img
    fp = bpy.path.abspath(img.filepath)
    pardir = os.path.dirname(fp)
    sufx = fp.split('.')[-1]
    if img_count > 1:
        img_name = mat_name + '_' + str(img_count)
    else:
        img_name = mat_name
    img.name = img_name
    new_path = os.path.join(pardir, img_name + '.' + sufx)
    bpy.ops.image.save_as(override, filepath=new_path)

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat_imgs = 0
    if mat.use_nodes:
        nt = mat.node_tree.nodes
        for n in nt:
            if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                mat_imgs += 1
                rename_image(n.image, mat.name, mat_imgs)
    else:
        for s in mat.texture_slots:
            if s is not None and s.texture.type == 'IMAGE':
                mat_imgs += 1
                rename_image(s.texture.image, mat.name, mat_imgs)

editor.type = old_type
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to fully work as I'd hoped. :( The images do get outputted with the name as intended however, all of the images that do get saved are a picture of the UV grid that's built into blenders UV editor tab. (I don't have it set to use that either.)  I'm using multitexture mode and I don't use the texture tab if that matters since the game only reads the material name. https://puu.sh/BC1L3/7974d5fa9e.bmp

Comment: @Shadow I see what I was doing wrong, this script should be right.